# NiFi: ParitionRecord processor for grouping

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a JSON message coming into the `partition record` processor where I group records based
on a date column `partition_dt`. 
Now I need to filter some records within this partition based on some other column (Ex: `/text:equals('XXX')`).
Is there a way like I can add multiple columns in `partitionrecord` processor within the same `partition column`?
Conditional statements to group records??

[image]

How do I approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be a two step process, filter then partition, or partition then filter.

You can use QueryRecord to write a SQL select statement for the filtering.

Comment: Thanks Bryan!. 
Its a avro-json message. What should be the order of steps/processors I need to use to accomplish this filtering logic before partition?

Comment: You can do QueryRecord -> PartitionRecord or PartitionRecord -> QueryRecord, it doesn't really matter the order. I guess filtering first could be better.